# "~たい"-form and associated particle usage

Tags: particles, particle-が, relative-clauses, i-adjectives, subordinate-clauses

My question is about the "~たい"-form ("want to").
I know that in a sentence containing this form, you can use は to mark the person who desires something. For example, "私は、東京に行きたい".

But then I came across this sentence:

> あなたが一番したいことはなんですか？

I translated it as "What is the thing you want to do most?".
So here, が is the particle used to mark the one who desires something.

Now, for my question: Can が always be used to mark the one who desires something in a "~たい"-sentence, or is it something that is limited to relative clauses such as the one in the second example?

In extension, is it okay to say "私がケーキを食べたい" or "私がケーキが食べたい"? Sounds a bit strange to me, but then again, my Japanese isn't really great yet.
But anyways, thanks for reading through my question!

Answer (score 5):

> 「あなた**が**一番{いちばん}したいこと**は**なんですか？」

This sentece is perfect in every way and it means what you said -- "**What is the thing you want to do most?**".

> Can が always be used to mark the one who desires something in a "~たい"-sentence, or is it something that is limited to relative clauses such as the one in the second example?

It is the latter.

「あなた**が**一番したい」 is a relative clause that modifies the noun 「こと」.  Inside relative clauses, the topic/subject-marker is ***always*** 「**が**」.  This 「が」 just cannot be replaced by a 「は」.

To use 「あなた**は**」(instead of 「あなた**が**」) correctly to say practically the same thing would be to say:

「あなた**は**なに**が**一番したいですか？」

Using 「は」 is correct and natural because it is not used inside a relative clause or any kind of sub-clause in the sentence just above.

> is it okay to say "私**が**ケーキ**を**食べたい" or "私**が**ケーキ**が**食べたい"?

***Only when the context calls for it, yes***.

Let me first talk about English.  Consider these two short conversations.

1)  A: Who are you?  B: I'm Bob.

2)  A: Which one of you is Bob?  B: I'm Bob.

Did you read B's two replies with the same intonation?  I highly doubt it even though I know almost no English.

In Japanese, in 1) B would say 「ボク**は**ボブです。」 and in 2), 「ボク**が**ボブです。」.  Surprised?

Back to your sentences..

If I asked you 「何が食べたいの？」(What would you like to eat?), you should reply 「ボク**は**ケーキが食べたい。」 The focus is on what kind of food rather than who the eater is.

If, however, I asked 「誰{だれ}がケーキを食べたいの？」(Who wants to eat a cake?), you should reply 「ボク**が**ケーキを食べたい。」 The focus is on ***who among the group***, not what s/he wants to eat.

I know this is not easy, but **you will get there one day**. ← That part in bold was a 「は」 sentence, BTW.  J-learners use 「が」 ***way*** too often and I have never quite understood why.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the first sentence, but I've always seen the relative clause used. This is in a bit of a contrast to the Ⅹがほしい construction. If you haven't learned that form yet, you might later! It's also used to describe wants, but in a different way. So also try to keep the two forms straight!

In addition to the answer detailed about は　and が　, a resource that explains the semantic distinction very well is Jay Rubin's "Making Sense of Japanese". It's a collection of essays by Rubin, but a major point of his is explaining the difference in context, which is often not conveyed well by Japanese language learning classes to start with and so many of us J-learners run across not knowing when to use which one appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it!